# How to get better error messaging from nightwatch when running tests in parallel

Tags: nightwatch.js

We have a problem when we run our nightwatch tests in parallel and there is a problem with the setup, for example the selenium grid is not available. The tests execute very quickly and we get no error messages.

```
Started child process for: folder1/test1
Started child process for: folder1/test2
Started child process for: folder1/test3
Started child process for: folder1/test4

>> folder1/test1 finished.  
>> folder1/test2 finished.  
>> folder1/test3 finished.  
>> folder1/test4 finished.
```

But when I run the tests serially, I get a good error message like

```
Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server


Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ status: 13, 
value: { message: 'Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, name=Test1, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, uuid=ab54872b-10ee-43a1-bf65-7676262fa647, platform=ANY}]',
 class: 'org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException' } }
```

Why don't I get the good error message when running in parallel mode? Is there something I can change so I get the good error message in parallel mode?

Answer (score 0):

By setting

```
live_output: true
```

in your nightwatch config file, you'll see logs while running in parallel.

More information: [config-basic](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/gettingstarted/configuration/config-basic-settings.md)